# How to efficiently mask an image?

Tags: image-processing

I want to extract/cut out a part of an image. Since my mask is not rectangular I want to set pixels that are not masked to zero (black). My current approach is something like this:

```
img = Import["path/to/image/image.jpg"];
{x, y, temp} = Dimensions@ImageData[img];
center = {100, 100};
radius = 30;
pixels = 
  Select[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, x}, {j, 0, y}], 1],
    (center[[1]] - #[[1]])^2 + (center[[1]] - #[[2]])^2 > radius^2 &];
ReplaceImageValue[img, Map[# -> 0 &, pixels]]
```

Even though this works, it is extremely slow for large images. Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to use the image processing functions that handle the image in its entirety, not work with individual pixels. The most straightforward way is to use a black and white "mask image" and then use `ImageMultiply`. This is not too hard, although you have to be careful to get the width and height of the mask right. For example:

```
img = Import["http://www.anderson-tours.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Eiffel-Tower-Paris-France.jpg"];
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
Show[ImageMultiply[img, ColorNegate@Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {w, h}], ImageSize -> {w, h}]], ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: cropped]

The mask in this example is `ColorNegate@Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {w, h}]`.

To generate arbitrary mathematically defined masks `RegionPlot` might be a good option:

```
Binarize@RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False]
```

Answer (score 2):

`HighlightImage` produces really nice results:

```
i = Thumbnail@Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Dalia_Grybauskaite_2014_by_Augustas_Didzgalvis.jpg"];
DiskRec[{xMin_,yMin_},{xMax_,yMax_}] := 
  Disk[ ({xMin,yMin}+{xMax,yMax})/2, 1.1({xMax,yMax}-{xMin,yMin})/2];

ImageCrop@HighlightImage[i, DiskRec @@@ FindFaces[i], "Remove"]
```

[image: picture of Dalia Grybauskaite face]